# Apply formatting rules to an entire eclipse work space

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

So, we are integrating another project in our code base. It does not follow our formatting rules. I have auto-formatting upon save configured. So, I could go to each file and save it again but is there a way to script Eclipse so that it applies formatting rules to every single file in my workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Source -> Clean up...`, `Use custom profile -> Configure...`. it has more powerful options there.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the project(s) (can multi-select) and choose `Source -> Format` in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in Package Explorer, then right-click and select the Source menu.  Some of the other views (e.g., Navigator) won't show this option.